# Apply slide specific CSS in ioslides_presentation on specified div classes only

Tags: css, r, css-selectors, r-markdown, ioslides

### How can I change the h2 header styles for specific slides only using the {} syntax?

I want to create a html presentation using `rmarkdown` and `ioslides`.

Some of the main slides should include images, and their titles should not overlap the image.

I am trying to influence their layout using some css ID (or class) specified in the `www/cust.css` file.

#### markdown:

````
---
title: "TITLE"
subtitle: "subtitle"
output:
   ioslides_presentation:
    css: www/cust.css
---

# Main 0

## sub

# Main 1 {.cust-1 .rcorners}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("www/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg")
` ``
# Main 2 {.cust-2}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("www/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg")
` ``

# Main 3 {#cust-3 .rcorners}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("www/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg")
` ``

# Main 4 {#cust-4}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("www/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg")
` ``
````

#### css

```
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {
  left: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 115px 115px;
}

.cust-1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.rcorners img{
  border-radius: 45px;
  padding: 20px;
}


.cust-2 h2{
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

#cust-3 h2{
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

#cust-4 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.auto-fadein h2{
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  top: 0px;
}

.gdbar img {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

.gdbar {
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 170px !important;
}

aside.gdbar {
  left: initial;
  right: 0;breaker.s
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-position: right;
}

<style>
div.footnotes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
```

However the problem i am facing is that i can't influence the `h2` header class via the `{.cust-x}` or `{#cust-x}` syntax.

It either influences the image and subtitle:

[image]

or, if i use `h2`like this:

```
.cust-2 h2{
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}
```

it has no influence whatsoever.

[image]

Usually these markdown first level header slides are using this css:

```
.auto-fadein h2{
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

But i cant change this class because it will interfere with the title page, etc.

#### EDIT

The syntax: {} works fine if i try to target other html objects for examle using this css style:

```
.rcorners img{
  border-radius: 45px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

gives me rounded image corners in example 1 and three where it is applied.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

As you figured out, `.cust-1 h2 {}` wasn't targeting the heading you wanted. This is because the HTML structure is different than you thought.

### How do you know how to target the element you want?

Step 1: Click *Knit to HTML (ioslides)* in RStudio

Step 2: Click *Open in Browser*

[image: Screenshot 1]

Step 3: Use Developer Tools (i.e., press the F12 key in your browser)

You can see that the HTML structure is the following:

```
<hgroup class="auto-fadein">
  <h2>Main 1</h2>
</hgroup>
<article id="main-1" class="cust-1">
  ...
</article>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 2]

## Solution 1

For example, to target the `<h2>` in the fourth slide (i.e., *Main 1*) use the following CSS:

```
/* Style the position of the <h2> wrapper */
slide[data-slide-num='4'] .auto-fadein {
  /* Your CSS */
}

/* Style the <h2> */
slide[data-slide-num='4'] h2 {
  /* Your CSS */
}
```

See `my-presentation.Rmd` and `styles.css` below for the full solution.

**my-presentation.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
date: "2023-05-30"
---

# Main 0

## sub

# Main 1 {.cust-1}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
# Main 2 {.cust-2}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```

# Main 3 {#cust-3}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```

# Main 4 {#cust-4}

```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
````

**styles.css**

```
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {
  left: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 115px 115px;
}

/**************** Slide 4 ****************/
/* Style the position of the <h2> wrapper */
slide[data-slide-num='4'] .auto-fadein {
  bottom: 60px;
}

/* Style the <h2> */
slide[data-slide-num='4'] h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

/**************** Slide 5 ****************/
/* Style the position of the <h2> wrapper */
slide[data-slide-num='5'] .auto-fadein {
  bottom: 60px;
}

/* Style the <h2> */
slide[data-slide-num='5'] h2 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

/**************** Slide 6 ****************/
/* Style the position of the <h2> wrapper */
slide[data-slide-num='6'] .auto-fadein {
  bottom: 60px;
}

/* Style the <h2> */
slide[data-slide-num='6'] h2 {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

/**************** Slide 7 ****************/
/* Style the position of the <h2> wrapper */
slide[data-slide-num='7'] .auto-fadein {
  bottom: 60px;
}

/* Style the <h2> */
slide[data-slide-num='7'] h2 {
  color: purple;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.gdbar img {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

.gdbar {
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 170px !important;
}

aside.gdbar {
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-position: right;
}

div.footnotes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You didn't understand what I wrote above. I'll try to simplify.

If you write:

```
# Main 1 {.cust-1}
```

The HTML structure will be the following:

```
<hgroup class="auto-fadein">
  <h2>Main 1</h2>
</hgroup>
<article id="main-1" class="cust-1">
  ...
</article>
```

**Meaning, you can't style the `<h2>` the way you want to (i.e., with the following CSS: `.cust-1 h2 {}`) because it's not a child or descendant of the `<article>` with the `class="cust-1"`.** See *Solution 1*.

But if you really want to style the `<h2>` with a class, then see *Solution 2*.

## Solution 2

You can add a class to the `<h2>` like this:

```
<h2 class="main-1">Main 1</h2>
```

See `my-presentation.Rmd` and `styles.css` below for the full solution.

**my-presentation.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
date: "2023-05-30"
---

# Main 0

## sub

#
```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
<h2 class="main-1">Main 1</h2>

#
```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
<h2 class="main-2">Main 2</h2>

#
```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
<h2 class="main-3">Main 3</h2>

#
```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.cap= "an img caption", out.width= '50%', fig.pos='top'}
knitr::include_graphics("./SMPTE_Color_Bars.png")
```
<h2 class="main-4">Main 4</h2>
````

**styles.css**

```
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {
  left: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 115px 115px;
}

h2.main-1,
h2.main-2,
h2.main-3,
h2.main-4 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
}

/**************** Main 1 ****************/
h2.main-1 {
  color: blue;
}

/**************** Main 2 ****************/
h2.main-2 {
  color: red;
}

/**************** Main 3 ****************/
h2.main-3 {
  color: green;
}

/**************** Main 4 ****************/
h2.main-4 {
  color: purple;
}

.gdbar img {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

.gdbar {
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 170px !important;
}

aside.gdbar {
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-position: right;
}

div.footnotes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

## Output

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Thank you this could be a workaround, however (maybe i was unclear in my question) i want to apply a css style by referencing it in the markdown file using the {.cust} and not the other way around writing a separate style for each slide. For some reason using img tag works fine and only targets the images in that silde.

Comment: @user12256545 I don't understand this part: *I want to apply a CSS style by referencing it in the markdown file using the {.cust} and not the other way around, writing a separate style for each slide.* What do you mean? I don't understand why my answer isn't what you aim for. Every `<h2>` has a different color, so I was able to target a certain `<h2>`. What's your goal?

Comment: @user12256545 Can you please give me some feedback?

Comment: hi idealy i want to use the arguments in the markdown headers brackets to specify which css styles should be applied ( ie {.cust})

Comment: @user12256545 I edited my answer. See *Solution 2*, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: no its exactly not how i want it, i know i can use direct html , but i want to use the bracket syntax. I will edit my question to make it more clear"

Comment: @user12256545 Did you read the update? You can't style the `<h2>` because it's not a child or descendant of the `<article>` with the `class="cust-1"` if you write `# Main 1 {.cust-1}` in the markdown file.